# Suppressing stubborn console output on system calls in Ruby

Tags: ruby, imagemagick-convert, output-redirect, console-output

I'm calling imagemagik's convert program from within ruby to convert image types. I'm redirecting both stdout and stderr to /dev/null but I'm still getting console text. It only occurs when converting FROM webp so I suspect it's output from the Ubuntu webp package.

```
buffer = `convert -quiet "#{temp_dir}#{tmp_image_filename}" "#{temp_dir}#{new_image_filename}" > /dev/null 2>&1`
```

Output:

```
Decoded /tmp/magick-3658rrhNn7wh4IW2. Dimensions: 580 x 300 . Format: lossy. Now saving...
Saved file /tmp/magick-3658nGuNL-bzCkRA
```

Is this tty output? I can't figure out how to capture and suppress it. I added the quiet attribute to convert command line but it had no affect (another reason I suspect webp is the culprit). I've tried several other tips in my stackoverflow search with system, IO, wrapping in : $(...), etc to no avail.  Any help?

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: Have you tried using [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html)? Backticks are only suitable for quick'n'dirty hacks IMO.

Comment: No I haven't, looks like a good option. There's actually an example with convert in the docs LoL! I'll report back... THX!

Comment: Open3 will also save you from launching a shell (which will parse the command line and then exec `convert`) and leave you open to unpleasant quoting and escaping issues that can cause a lot of problems unless you're very careful. Open3 won't involve a shell so a lot of problems just go away.

Comment: Open3 is the way to go. Backticks are a dirty hack and honestly shouldn't even be allowed in Ruby without a special flag (`ruby --yolo` perhaps?). They're exceptionally dangerous if used incorrectly.

Comment: using Open3.capture3 produces the same results. The convert output (more likely the webp output) bleeds thru to the console...

Comment: What happens if you run it manually in the shell with output redirection. Same problem?

Comment: I found the code where this output comes from. It is a command `dwebp` which is used as a delegate for IM. It's a simple `printf` statement. You can search for `now saving` in this code: https://searchcode.com/file/22469641/libwebp-0.1.3/examples/dwebp.c/

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Using backticks with 2>&1 redirection gets rid of the webp output on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thanks everyone. For some reason it's working now. Open3.capture3 successfully suppresses the output, tho I don't know why it wasn't before. Now I can't even reproduce the case where capture3 allows anything to slip thru. Thanks for tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered in the comments. I moved to Open3.capture3 using a format like below and the console text from webp is captured.

```
stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("convert -flatten \"#{$temp_dir}#{tmp_image_filename}\" \"#{$temp_dir}#{@image_filename}\"")
```